# NHibernate, MySQL (InnoDB) and locking rows

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, locking, innodb

I have got a counter in a database table (Mysql with InnoDB). On the client I am using NHibernate.

What is the recommended way to update the counter in a safe manner (just one client is able to update the value at the same time) - so we don't get any duplicates ?

- using MySQL locking techniques (SELECT FOR UPDATE)
- using NHibernate locking Session.Lock ....

the NHibernate manual says that it is database dependend if Session.Lock works or not. Does it work with MySQL and InnoDB ?

Does anybody have more information to this topic or some hints ?